# Is there a possibility to clone FE Truecrypt hard drive?

Tags: truecrypt

Is there a possibility to clone fully encrypted (with bootloader) hard drive (Truecrypt 7.1a) and somehow get a copy (binary one) of encrypted data or is it just impossible even to access this hard drive since it's fully encrypted?

Comment: Do you know the key to decrypt it? And are you running Windows on it?

Comment: it's Win7 inside, I do not know the password.

Comment: Without the password, given that there's no flaw in True Crypt, you cannot get an **unencrypted** copy of the disk.

Comment: but can I get a encrypted copy?

Comment: Yes of course. Just do a sector by sector copy for example with `dd` as davidgo already mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clone the entire drive using something that does a bit copy (dd under linux for example). The data, of-course, will be encrypted on the copy as well so you still need to unlock the drive.

BTW, the bootloader is, if I understand correctly (and I'm fairly sure I do) not encrypted.

Nothing you can do in software can reliably prevent access to the raw disk (unless you somehow you can make it damage the disk, eg too many writes on an SSD, or programming the heads to smash into the drive)

Comment: are you 100% I can actually access fully encrypted drive? I heard it's simply impossible, hence the stories that hard drives confiscated from criminals are held physically, since binary copies can't be made and thus the reason to keep those drives physically.

Comment: Yes, Im 100% sure. I dont know what you have read, however I wonder if someone is confusing TPM on the computer with the hard drive?  Some encryption systems (including Bitlocker) can take advantage of hardware on the motherboard (ie tpm) to make a disk useless if removed from the original system. (and ive implemented something similar on my Linux system using LUKS). TPM is not embedded into the hard drive though.

Comment: (Im on a shocking connection in the middle of the ocean, so cant practically research it now but) there are disks (mainly ssd's) which encrypt the drive in hardware - but this is done to allow it to be quickly erased by overwriting a key rather then the disk. This acts in hardware and is unrelated to truecrypt which is a software solution.

Comment: BitLocker and VeraCrypt do not have any protection to prevent copying the blob of data that exists on the HDD.  BitLocker will require a recovery key if the TPM configuration is modified.  That is the extent of the protection.  FDE only prevent malicious users who don’t have the pass phrase to decrypt the blob of data

Comment: Having said that, how things are with truecrypt 7.1a? Is it possible to make a binary copy of a FDE hard drive and somehow in a future use password - in case, it will be revealed to user in possesion of binary copy?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with any encryption technology - the only questions are how secure is the encryption algorythm, passphrase and aparent randomness if resulting output.